# Alignment issues setting custom x-axis in d3 ; how to hide the last label

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

## VIEW HERE: [Screencap of chart I'm working with.](http://cvlassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Screen%20Shot%202017-02-22%20at%202.49.41%20PM-2.png)

#### Issue with custom-defined d3.js x-axes values

Hi all--

As you can see from the chart above (which actually kind of contains five smaller area charts within it), I need the x-axis labels to be nonlinear and for them to repeat the same year span `2011` and `2015` at the beginning and end of each chart. I'm having **immense difficulty** getting them to align properly on the x-axis while also scale down to different screen sizes. Here's a snippet from where I'm defining those values:

```
            svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("stroke-width", 10)
            .attr("stroke", "#ccc");

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 600])
            .range([height, 0]);
        var yAxis = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis1")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(6));

        var xScale1 = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([0, width-margin.left]);
        var xAxis1 = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis1")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale1).ticks(5).tickFormat(2011));

        var xScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([margin.left, width]);
        var xAxis2 = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis2")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale2).ticks(5).tickFormat(2015));
```

Also, you'll notice from my [full source code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/carlvlewis/6b8f23e90301d4bd4e72cbe651d50387/raw/acff3a6f1071240c9107fa450f7dab3e5cb5aa46/index.html) I used a simple `break;` statement to separate the charts from each other, but the problem is that I can't add `break;` at the beginning of the array, and the `break;` doesn't render at the end. Snippet below:

```
        function getData(jsonData){

            var data = [];
            var twoData = [[], [], [], [], []];
            for(var i = 0 ; i < jsonData.length ; i ++){
                switch(jsonData[i].Month){

            case "Jan":
                        twoData[0].push(jsonData[i].Sales);
                        break;
                    case "Feb":
                        twoData[1].push(jsonData[i].Sales);
                        break;
                    case "Mar":
                        twoData[2].push(jsonData[i].Sales);
                        break;
                    case "Apr":
                        twoData[3].push(jsonData[i].Sales);
                        break;
                    case "May":
                        twoData[4].push(jsonData[i].Sales);
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: FWIW: I figured this issue out. See [project](http://carlvlewis.net/carlvlewis_axischallenge.html) and [source code as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/carlvlewis/8a5b1cc987217607a47bd7d4e0fffacb).